# Can I Use Append and Load function in Jquery at thesame time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$(".eventName").click(
        function () {
            var eventId = $(this).attr('id');
            var role    = $(this).attr('dir');
            var todo = 'viewDetails';
            $("#details").load("plugins/company_calendar/calendar.php?eventId="+ eventId +"&todo="+ todo +"&role="+ role );
            $(this).find('.eventDetails').css("left", $(this).position().left + 20);
            $(this).find('.eventDetails').css("top", $(this).position().top + $(this).height());
            $(".eventDetails").fadeIn(10);
        }
    );
```

Is it possible to append the data that I load in the details??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry load just replace's the content of the element with te result.

You should do

```
$.get("plugins/company_calendar/calendar.php?eventId="+ eventId +"&todo="+ todo +"&role="+role, function(response) {
    $("#details").append(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can do something like this:

```
$("#details").append($("<div id='appender1'></div>"));
$("#appender1").load("plugins/company_calendar/calendar.php?eventId="+ eventId +"&todo="+ todo +"&role="+ role );
```

of course you'll need to count the appenders if you need to use them more than once.

Comment: no id solution: `var appender = $("<div></div>").appendTo("#details1"); appender.load("/foo.php?blah=qwert");`